# Find the inverse function of $f(x)=\frac{1-x}{-x}$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

When I tried solving for the inverse of $f(x)=\frac{1-x}{-x}$, I got this:

$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$

I know that the way to check my answer would be to take the inverse of the inverse I just found, but this is what I get:

$f^{-1}(f^{-1}(x))=1-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x-1}{-x}$

The last part, when multiplied by $\frac{-1}{-1}$ is indeed my original function, but am I allowed to do that? And why does that get lost when taking the inverse?

Comment: $\frac{-1}{-1} = 1$, so yes you can multiply by it. It's the same concept as $\frac{4}{2} = 2$ or $\frac{-2}{-1} = 2$

Answer (score 0):

A better way to check your answer is;

the composite functions of both should be
equal to x.

$f(f^{-1}(x))=x$

and

$f^{-1}(f(x))=x$

Comment: When I tried $f(f^{-1}(x))$ I ended up with $(1 - 1/(1 - x)) (-1 + x)$... and when I tried $f^{-1}(f(x))$ I got $1/(1 + (1 - x)/x)$ which makes me think that my answer isn't correct, even though it sort-of checked out above... What am I missing here?

Comment: when I tried, $(-1)/(x-1)$    maybe check your calculations and see if you missed a sign.

Answer (score 0):

It really helps to simplify $f(x)$ so that $x$ only appears once in its definition.

$$f(x)=\frac{1-x}{-x}  = 1-\frac 1x  $$

$$f^{-1}(x)= \frac{1}{1-x}$$

$$f(f^{-1}(x)) = 1-\frac{1}{   \frac{1}{1-x}   }      
=1-(1-x)=x
$$
$$ f^{-1}( f(x)) =  \frac{1}{1-(   1-\frac 1x    )}  =\frac{1}{\frac 1x}=x$$